# unable to generate single invoice for multiple order of single user

Tags: jbilling

If I create 4 orders for single user and I want to create single invoice for all 4 order. 
I am able to do this through API but how can i do this by Billing UI. If i run billing process, it will create invoice but billing process will run for all existing user not for particular user.

Answer (score 1):

Musaddique -

1. Start one of the 4 orders that belong to one user, to begin with,
   click on **Generate Invoice** button on the show order page
2. This will create an Invoice that includes the selected order only
3. Go back to the orders list, select one by one, each of the remaining
   un-invoiced orders, and click on the button **APPLY TO INVOICE**
4. This action will list all the available Invoices for that customer,
       you may select the most recently created one and click submit

Hope this helps.

Vikas